# How to create a custom react-hot-toast but keeping the default animations

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-toast

Creating a customized Toast seems easy enough when using [react-hot-toast](https://react-hot-toast.com/):

```
toast.custom(<div>Hello World</div>);
```

But it seems to loss the default animations. Docs only mention how to create customized animations, is there an easy way to reuse the already existing **enter** and **exit** animations on a customized toast?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I am trying to do the same thing, without success